# How to specify parametrized generics for Kotlin property?

Tags: kotlin

I have a method in Kotlin that looks like this:

```
fun <T : Event> addEventListener(eventClass: Class<T>, eventHandler: EventHandler<T>) {
    eventListeners.put(eventClass, eventHandler)        
}
```

Also I have a property `eventListeners` but I can't figure out how to define it so it will have the same generic type, kinda like this

```
private val eventListeners = HashMap<Class<T>, EventHandler<T>>()
```

Obviously `T` is not defied for the property `eventListeners` and that is what I'm struggling with. 
Just so everybody knows, I understand that `T` can be defined for the whole class (e.g. `class MyClass<T: Event> {...}`) and that way it will be simple, but in this particular case I can't do it.

Comment: How do you plan to use the data stored in `eventListeners`? As long as `T` is constrained to `Event`, we can declare: `private val eventListeners =
 HashMap<Class<Event>, EventHandler<Event>>()`, and use that interface, but we'll need to check type/upcast if we want to use each of the individual subtypes stored in the set.

Comment: The usecase is pretty simple, I want to able to do `myClass.addEventListener(subClassOfEvent.class, myEventHandler)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it safely. You'll need to use e.g. `eventListeners: HashMap<Class<*>, EventHandler<*>>` and cast in `getEventListener` which should be safe *if you only access `listeners` with these 2 functions*. It's reasonable to extract into a separate class which would prevent direct access to the map.